# unable to connect to local server in SSMS 2014 (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, connection, ssms, sql-server-2014

I need to run SSMS for my own practice and create a local database on the machine. But I am unable to connect to the local server

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 installed. It comes with SQL Server Management Studio version 12.0.4100.1

I type the server name

```
(localdb)\v11.0
```

But I am getting an error

[image: a network-related or instance-specific error occured]

I tried searching for server names by clicking on the 'Browse for more' option in the drop down of SSMS connection window, but could not find any server mentioned there.

I ran SQL Server Configuration Manager and went to SQL Server Services. There are no items available there

[image: sql server connection manager shows no services]

I tried running the below command through command prompt

```
NET START SQLSERVERAGENT
```

but it gave 'server name invalid' error

[image: sql server service name invalid]

Can someone suggest other steps to debug and run the local server

Comment: did you open the `SQL Server Configuration Manager for 2014`? if you have old SQL server installed, and you happened to open the old manager, it will not show you any instance that is newer than the manager

Comment: Open up your `Services` from the `Administrative Tools` and see if you have SQL Server services running or not started.

Comment: I have the SQL Server Configuration Manager opened for 2014. the version is 2014.0.120.2000.08.

Comment: I also did: Right click on computer icon > click Manage > expand 'Services and Applications'. I could not find any service named SQL Server or Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Then it sounds like to me that it's not installed. Just the client services (SSMS) is installed. What are you running for your desktop?

Comment: It sounds like you just installed the client connectivity tools and not the sql server db engine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ross Bush and @WEI_DBA
I had installed the setup SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe. I didn't realize that this setup did not contain the provision to install the db engine. I ran another installer SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe. And while running this setup, I selected the database engine services checkbox and installed. I am now able to connect to the local server.

Thanks Once againm for your help!